# What is the maximum multiplicity of intersection of two nonsingular conics at a common point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am aware of the following:

> Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be projective plane curves, with $ X $ nonsingular and not contained in $ Y. $ Then the sum of the multiplicities of intersection of $ X $ and $ Y $ at all points of $ X \cap Y $ equals the product of the degrees of $ X $ and $ Y. $

This is a form of Bézout's theorem, but I don't know how relevant this is to the question since the question concerns the maximum intersection multiplicity of two nonsingular conics at a particular point of intersection.

Comment: It is possible to have two curves whose intersection multiplicity at a common single point is equal to the product of their degrees.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @ParthivBasu To be honest, I didn't think of the question in these terms. I'm wondering what the maximum multiplicity is at the point, and the only result I could think of that seemed relevant to this question is the theorem. However, I suppose that is also an interesting question.

Comment: The intersection multiplicity of two curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ (with no common components) at a point in which they meet is bounded by the product of their degrees. Now can this bound be realized? The answer is yes. Take for example $V(yz-x^2)$ and $V(z)$. Their intersection multiplicity at $(0:1:0)$ is $2$.